# Homotopy groups of $MO(2)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Have there been any computations of the higher homotopy groups of $MO(2)$, the Thom space of the universal $O(2)$-bundle? Thom himself noted in his landmark 1954 paper that
$$
\pi_1(MO(2))=0,\quad \pi_2(MO(2))=\mathbb{Z}/2,\quad\pi_3(MO(2))=0,\quad \pi_4(MO(2))=\mathbb{Z}.
$$
By the Pontrjagin-Thom construction $\pi_n(MO(2))$ is the group of cobordism classes of embeddings of closed $(n-2)$-manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where a cobordism is an embedding in $\mathbb{R}^n\times [0,1]$.

Comment: I haven't sat down to do the computation, but $\pi_5(MO(2))$ should be reasonably computable.  All $3$-manifolds embed in $\mathbb R^5$ so it boils down to the question of which of their null-cobordisms embed in $\mathbb R^6$, which shouldn't be too hard... but I haven't finished my morning cup of tea yet.  I suspect somebody has already done this computation.

Comment: A preliminary computation with the unstable Adams spectral sequence seems to support Ryan: it looks to me like $\pi_5(MO(2)) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, both. Which version of the unstable Adams spectral sequence are you using, Tyler? I would very much like to check what $\pi_7$ is, if possible.

Comment: @MarkGrant The one based on Ext in the (nonabelian) category of unstable algebras over the Steenrod algebra; it looks like the Postnikov tower might be a more pedestrian approach. I think I'm getting that $\pi_7$ is finite with cyclic factors of size $2$, $4$, and $3$. Is that useful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of references which show that $\pi_5(MO(2))=\mathbb{Z}/2$.

*Suzuki, H.*, [**On the realization of the Stiefel-Whitney characteristic classes by submanifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2748/tmj/1178244748), Tohoku Math. J., II. Ser. 10, 91-115 (1958). [ZBL0107.17001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0107.17001).

The proof uses the Postnikov tower. The conclusion is on page 108.

*Zvagel’skij, M. Yu.*, [**Cobordisms of embeddings with codimension two**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1011325713206), J. Math. Sci., New York 104, No. 4, 1276-1282 (2001); translation from Zap. Nauchn. Semin. POMI 252, 40-51 (2001). [ZBL1052.57042](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1052.57042).

The proof here is geometric, and (for me) harder to follow. This paper also contains a proof that $\pi_6(MO(2))=0$.